# How to do CRUD on datagridview with an anonymous type datasource

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, entity, crud

I have a datagridview. I fetch data from database using linq to entity and i assign the list that is returned from linq to the datasource property of datagridview.

```
private void ucRecipe_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var v2 = (from malzeme in bshEntity.Malzemeler select new { malzeme.ID, malzeme.Kod, malzeme.Ad, malzeme.Tip}).ToList();
      dgvMaterial.DataSource = v2;
}
```

I want to do some CRUD operation on the list that is assigned to dgvMaterial.Datasource and then refresh dgvMaterial. But i cant reach the list (v2) from other methods(like button click event). How can i reach that anonymous type from other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of C# you are using, so I am giving you an answer using dynamic.

I am casting the anonymous type to a dynamic, the iterating over each row and then I access the field values like properties. This is assuming you know the property names in the anonymous type.

```
this.dgvMaterial.ItemsSource = v2.ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < dgvMaterial.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var row = dgvMaterial.Items[i] as dynamic;
    var fieldOne = row.FieldOne;
    var fieldTwo = row.FieldTwo;
}
```

I hope this works for you.